# existence of elements in Banach space

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

I want to prove

If $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$ are bounded linear and linearly independent functionals on a Banach space then there exists n elements $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n$ such that $f_i(z_j)=\delta_{i,j}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic beats of the construction are pretty similar to Gram-Schmidt.

If there's one functional $f_1$, then linear independence implies $f_1 \neq 0$, so there exists $x_1 \in X \setminus \operatorname{ker} f_1$. Choose $z_1 = x_1 / f_1(x_1)$.

Suppose that we have bounded linear, linearly independent functionals $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ and corresponding $z_1, \ldots z_k$ with $f_i(z_j) = \delta_{i,j}$. Note that, if we have $f \in \operatorname{span}(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$, then
$$f = f(z_1)f_1 + \ldots f(z_k) f_k.$$
(You should prove this!) So, if we have $f_1, \ldots, f_k, f_{k+1}$ is linearly independent as well, then there exists some $x \in X$ such that
$$f_{k+1}(x) \neq f_{k+1}(z_1)f_1(x) + \ldots f_{k+1}(z_k)f_k(x)$$
Let $x_{k+1} = x - f_1(x)z_1 - \ldots - f_k(x)z_k$. Then $f_{k+1}(x) \neq 0$, but $f_i(x) = 0$ for $1 \le i \le k$. Choose $z_{k+1} = x / f_{k+1}(x)$.

Comment: thanks@Theo bendit

Comment: Sorry, now that I look, there were a couple of errors.